# .net MAUI: how to draw on canvas

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-6.0, maui

I pretty new to c# and maui.
I want to understand how can i draw on canvas. I read the docs and find something online.
I want to draw simple line.
[image]
What I did is created class inside `MauiProgram.cs`

```
namespace TestMauiX;
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

        return builder.Build();
    }
}

public class MyFirstDrawing : IDrawable
{
    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectangleF dirtyRect)
    {
        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
        canvas.StrokeSize = 6;
        canvas.DrawLine(10, 10, 90, 100);
    }
}
```

And then I have `MainPage.xaml` but how should I put that drawing inside?

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="TestMauiX.MainPage"
                 BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}">
    
        <ScrollView>
            <Grid RowSpacing="25" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,*"
                  Padding="{OnPlatform iOS='30,60,30,30', Default='30'}">
    
                <Label 
                    Text="Hello, World!"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                    FontSize="32"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
....
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently for preview MAUI apps you use a `GraphicsView` control for drawing like you would do on a `Canvas` control.

See the [`GraphicsView` MAUI docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/graphicsview).

An example:

1. Create your drawable...

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;

public class MyFirstDrawing : IDrawable
{
    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectangleF dirtyRect)
    {
        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
        canvas.StrokeSize = 6;
        canvas.DrawLine(10, 10, 90, 100);
    }
}
```

2. In your `ContentPage` add a reference to your drawable class in the `ContentPage.Resources` section.
   Then add a `GraphicsView` control to the page layout and set the `Drawable` property to the `Key` value set for your drawable in the `ContentPage.Resources` section using the `StaticResource` markup extension.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:drawable="clr-namespace:YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE"
             ...>
    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <drawable:MyFirstDrawing x:Key="MyDrawable" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView>
        <Grid RowSpacing="20" 
              RowDefinitions="Auto,*"
              Padding="{OnPlatform iOS='30,60,30,30', Default='30'}">

            <Label 
                Text="Hello, World!"          
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                Grid.Row="0"/>

            <GraphicsView 
                x:Name="Canvas"                 
                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                Drawable="{StaticResource MyDrawable}" 
                HeightRequest="100"           
                Grid.Row="1"/>
          </Grid>
     </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: What I missed everywhere, nowhere stated clearly is: 

You have to create your own class which implements IDrawable. Say it's called X.  
You also must create a GraphicsView (maybe in XAML) and assign an instance of X to the Drawable property of the GraphicsView. 
You can do this from code behind, no need to put this into the ContentPage.Resources.
Then when things are painted, the function   Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)  of X is called from by the system. THAT is the way you get to the canvas you can draw on.